# How do you create/register local notification settings in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification, xcode8

I am trying to update my app to Swift 3. I am making progress but I cannot figure out how to register local notification settings. This is my code which resides in the AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    if application.currentUserNotificationSettings?.categories?.count == 0 {
        // Updated Code
        let types: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

        let completeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "complete", title: "Complete", options: [])

        let ignoreAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ignore", title: "Ignore", options: [])

        let taskCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "taskCategory", actions: [completeAction, ignoreAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        // Old Code (stripped for simplicity)
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: _, categories: _)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    print(application.currentUserNotificationSettings?.categories?.count)
    return true
}
```

Comment: That is for push notifications. It doesn't answer my question on local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization([.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }
    return true
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just came upon this and the rest of Apple's documentation. I am currently piecing together the what I need. It isn't as simple of a change as I had hoped. It requires different logic than I have previously implemented.